# How do I read a multiline variable one line at a time?

Tags: linux, sh

I have a variable that we can call `largeVar` and has the following content:

```
var1="blah1"
var2="blah2"
var3="blah3"
```

So if I do a `printf "$largeVar"` I get the exact content above.  I need to, however, add these vars to my environment without creating a property file.  So I'm trying to do this:

```
for var in "$largeVar"
do 
   eval "$var"
done
```

But this is just eval the `$largeVar` and not each line.  So I then tried this:

```
while cat "$largeVar" | read var
do
   printf "$var"
done
```

This seems to work... kinda (I only tested with `printf` to see what would happen) but the final line says `echo : File name too long`

Is there anyway to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `cat "$largevar"` is just going to look for a FILE whose name starts with `var1=....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do `eval $largeVar` as environment variables can be separated with whitespace in bash.